# Trying to add an attribute to a Django crispy form input field

Tags: python, django, forms, attributes, django-widget-tweaks

I'm attempting to add an attribute to a django crispy form using Django-Widget-Tweaks. I followed instructions, however, instead of adding the 'disabled' attribute to the existing field, it's adding a whole new field to the form with the same name, id, class, etc and includes my'disabled' attribute (lol).
Here's my widget tweak code...

```
        {% crispy registration_form %}
        {{ registration_form.net_profit|attr:"disabled" }}
```

This is an image to the inspected html code that is generated. Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to copy the code.:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can copy the code, paste it into your post, and add three ticks to the top and bottom of the code

Comment: Hi,
Thanks but my problem isn't pasting the code here, as I have done so above, it was copying the html code from the inspect window. It wouldn't allow me to select the lines to copy.

Comment: Why don't you disable if from your form declaration before sending to the view

Comment: Hi, I wish it was that simple. As I'm using crispy forms, the field declarations will not accept 'disabled' as an attribute. I receive a syntax error. Here is a snippet from my declaration...
```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div('organization_name',css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                Div('phone', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
```

Comment: With help, I did get the disable to work with the following statement...
```
$("input#id_ticket_count").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```
However, with those fields disabled, even though I was plugging values into them through code, the form wouldn't save as Django still treated them as empty. Back to the drawing board.